# Spring batch with jdbc for audit data

Tags: spring, jdbc, jakarta-ee, spring-batch

Hi i have an requirement to update spring batch with jdbc

My requirement is

I have to audit the database table having emp details like name,age,project etc..
for ex the first row is having emp details like

```
name age project address phno.
sus  45   java    xyz     456
```

When i audit the phone number and save it in the same database table the table must be like

```
sus 45   java  xyz  456
sus null null  null 435
```

So the logic is like only key column and changed value will be reflected in the next row and other not changed column must be null

I have to do it with spring batch program with jdbc connectivity..

Please help me out to find out the logic and coding idea..

Comment: The question is unclear, do you have to do this at each update? Updates happen from an application you control?

Comment: Have you thought about using a database trigger?  You can compare new and old version.

Comment: @abalog yes i have to do it at each update...if i will update 10 time different information regrding that emp den 10 subsequent rows will hv to create with updated value and key column keeping unupdated value as null..

Comment: I would use triggers in this case probably and also use a different (tablename_audit) table for this purpose.

Comment: @abalogh i cant use different table,the update should be done in the same table...so can i use triggers in this scenario also?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can. See how to create an after-update trigger:

- [using Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php)
- [using MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)